# Labelling multiple equations on the same line, and referencing individual equations from it

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels

Consider the following array of three equations.

```
\begin{align}
a & =b\label{eq:eq1}\\
c & =d\label{eq:eq2}\\
e & =f\label{eq:eq3}
\end{align}
```

I would like to compact this by putting all three equations on the same line. However, I don't know how (or if it is even possible) to do this in such a way where the equations are labelled by say (1a-c), and where I can refer to the equations individually from outside the text (for example, by then calling equation (1a)). Having tried to put several labels on the same line in an align environment, LaTeX throws an error.

Does anyone know how to remedy this?

**UPDATE:** I would also like to achieve this, but where I have several lists of equations within align environments that I want to line up with each other. When I try:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
a & =b\label{eq:eq1}\\
c & =d\label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
e & =f\label{eq:eq1-1}\\
g & =h\label{eq:eq2-1}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}
```

all the equations end up being concentrated in the left side of the document. If I try using `multicols` instead of `minipage`, then I do get the two-column layout that I am after, but the equations do not line up vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting objective by (1) loading the `amsmath` package and making use of its `subequations` environment, (2) placing the three equations in `equation` environments and placing the `equation` environments in separate `minipage` environments of width `0.333\textwidth`, (3) placing the side by side minipages in a `subequations` environment, and (4) placing the `subequations` environment in a `center` environment. The purpose of Step 4 (the `center` environment) is to provide some vertical whitespace separation above and below the equations; this is advisable because the `minipage` environment clobber the vertical whitespace that's inserted by the `equation` environments.

To create cross-references to these equations, just use LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` (or `\eqref`) mechanism.

[image]

The framelines in the screenshot are generated by the `showframe` package and show the left- and right-hand edges of the textblock.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'subequations' environment and '\eqref' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage{showframe} % optional: draw framelines around text block

\begin{document}
\null

\begin{center}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{minipage}{0.333\textwidth}
  \begin{equation} \label{eq:1a}
  a=b
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.333\textwidth}
  \begin{equation} \label{eq:1b}
  c=d
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.333\textwidth}
  \begin{equation} \label{eq:1c}
  e=f
  \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}
\end{center}

\noindent
Cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:1b} and \eqref{eq:1c}.

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up code: I suggest you insert `\noindent` before the first `minipage` environment and affix `%` (the comment symbol) to the end of the first `\end{minipage}` line.

```
\begin{subequations}
\noindent % <-- new
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
a &= b \label{eq:eq1}\\
c &= d \label{eq:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}% % <-- terminate the line with "%"
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align}
e &= f \label{eq:eq1-1}\\
g &= h \label{eq:eq2-1}
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Now what if I instead want to make each equation a list of equations (e.g. within an align environment)? I would like to have a 2-by-2 array of equations with their own references and all lined up with each other - but having tried a multicol environment, it doesn't seem to work particularly well.

Comment: To give you an idea of what I want to achieve, please check the update on the main question.

Comment: @OGBond - Please see the addendum I posted just now.

Comment: Many thanks. To go one further, is there a way to make sure the equations in each minipage share the same vertical alignment? I am using a more complicated example involving fractions, and the vertical alignment of the equations in the second column are (very slightly) off from the first one.

Comment: @OGBond - The answer to your fairly abstract question, "is there a way", is a simple yes. Please post a new query, in which you might show the actual equations you're looking to align vertically. That'll make it much easier to provide specific advice.

Comment: I've managed to find a way that works with my specific equations. In particular, I was trying to find a way to write Maxwell's equations in such a way that they line up - using the phantom command to put in "hidden" parentheses seemed to do the trick. That said, I will pose a more general version of this question at some stage.